# copying data from a form field and placing it in an echo statement all within an $xml=simplexml_load_file function

Tags: php, javascript, syntax, onblur

I am loading and echoing data from an XML file through the `$xml=simplexml_load_file` function.  Everything is working perfectly, the code is as follows ( in part ):

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file('testfeed1.xml');
        $max = 12;
        $i = 1;
foreach($xml->someTag as $feed){ 
if ($i <= $max){

echo "<span class='previewImage' name='{$feed->some-subTag}' 
style='background:url({$feed->imageTag}) no-repeat center;'>";
                $i++;
            } 
          }  
    ?>
```

In this example, I am drawing a URL from a tag in the XML and placing it at the background for a given span, all the images in the array (if that is the right usage of the word) appear without any problems.

What I would very much like to figure out is how to make the background in this short example change base upon an `onBlur` function set in a form field which is also on the page.

So if I have the following code:

```
Image URL: <input type='text' name='smallImage' id='someId' 
value='{$feed->imageTag}' />
```

As you can see the field is pre-loaded with the "imageTag" from the XML here as well.

What syntax or function could I use to change the backgroud of the span above after a new URL has been written. I was under the presumption that the `onBlur` function would be the best.

```
<input type='text' name='smallImage' id='someId' value='{$feed->smallImage}' 
onblur="document.find(.imagePreview#{$feed->some-subTag}).setAttribute("background", .smallImage.someId.value);" />
```

Again, I am complettely new to js and php.

Thanks in advance for any tips, hints or tricks.

/Brian

Comment: `find()` is one of the jQuery object's methods.

Answer (score 0):

As sad as it is, i moidified the image swap function built into Dreamweaver to solve the issue.

Dreamweaver has a code which swaps images using `mouseOver` for a swap and `mouseOut` for a recovery of the original image (I am certain most people know this).

Instead of these I simply use the `onBlur` function to swap the image, left out any recovery swap, and I played with it so that the preview image is swapped with an image source entered in a certain field.

```
<p>
<img name='flipflop{$feed->individualTag}' src='{$feed->smallImage}' />
</p>
```

This above code the same.

For the field entry:

```
onblur="MM_swapImage('flipflop{$feed->individualTag}','',(this.value),1);" />
```

And of course i copied the MM-swapImage script and placed in the file.... obviously.

Not glamorous, not smart, not inventive, not talented ..... but functional.

And for a guy who knows as much js, jquery and php as I do.....  functionality is king.